How to verify i'm using the Kotlin 2 compiler K2
I'm migrating a rather large Android-App from Kotlin 1.9.x to 2.0. for testing purposes.
How can i test that this has worked? I have seen zero new errors/warnings in my code after the migration, which makes me very suspicious.

There weren't many breaking changes in Kotlin 2.0, so I am not surprised that there are no warnings/errors. How about just trying out some of the new features and see if they work?

You can call KotlinVersion.CURRENT to get the Kotlin version the code was compiled with.
